# Select dynamically in Bootstrap-select with multiple values not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have tried an example:
[this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32388954/how-to-select-dynamically-in-bootstrap-select-with-multiple-values)

and its working fine but when I tried to bind dynamically it's not working. Please anyone can help in this.

please find below code:

**Dropdown code:**

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="field-2" class="control-label">Dropdown</label>
 <select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" id="lstdrpdwn" name="lstdrpdwn">
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

** Jquery:**

```
 function FillDetail(id) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: '../Getdata',
            data: 'id=' + id,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    alert('[' + item.CooperativeUserID + ']');
                    $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('val', '[' + item.CooperativeUserID + ']');  //.val(item.CooperativeUserID);
                    $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('refresh');
                })
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Also i have tried to remove `//$('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('refresh');` the lines.

And aslo tried to refresh the selectpicker
 `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` its not working.

When I bind the values with static IDs it worked fine at the time of filling dropdown.

```
function filldropdown() {
        return $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: '../Getdropdown',
            data: 'id=0',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#lstdrpdwn").html("");
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    $("#lstdrpdwn").append($("<option></option>").val(val.ID).html(val.Name));
                });
                $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('refresh');
                $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('val', [2,5]);

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error on the console ?

Comment: no there is no error in console

Answer (score 1):

So thing is you have to give an array to selectpicker in order to set the vals.
you are doing it like this :

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    alert('[' + item.CooperativeUserID + ']');
                    $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('val', '[' + item.CooperativeUserID + ']');  //.val(item.CooperativeUserID);
                    $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('refresh');
                })
```

And a correct way shoul be like this :

```
var selected =  data.map(function(e) {
             return e.CooperativeUserID ;
           });
$('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('val', selected);
```

OR using the $.each :

```
var selected = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                 selected.push(item.CooperativeUserID);       

                    });
$('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('val', selected);
```

you can find an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/segito/0u3nw1wc/

Comment: please update your post with what you have tried i update the code by my side with $.each and it works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/segito/0u3nw1wc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying

i just tried like this and it worked for me.

**JQUERY**

```
function FillDetail(id) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: '../Getdata',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var array = item.CooperativeUserID.split(',');
                $('#lstdrpdwn').selectpicker('val', array);
            })
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please precise how your received data is formated to make your response helpful